# %-s formatting in C++

Tags: c++, printf

Can someone explain what does %-25s and %-90s do in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    printf ("%-25s %-90s","hello" ,"world");
}
```

Comment: Please avoid `using namespace std;`, it's bad practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Actually, using it within header files is really bad, since it will be propagated to any dependent files - but within a source file after all includes there I do not see an issue with 'using namespace std;' IMHO - but personally I like the explicit way

Answer (score 1):

From the reference for [std::printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), the `-` specifier after `%` is an optional flag that left-justifies the string to be printed:

> `-`: the result of the conversion is left-justified within the field (by default it is right-justified)

So your program will write out "hello" followed by 20 whitespace characters, and then "world" followed by 85 whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

`-25` means left justify text in 25 blocks (character spaces). and `%-90` means same just in 90 blocks. So for this:

```
printf ("|%-25s|%-15%|","hello", "world");
```

output would be:

```
|Hello                    |world          |
//          ^ 20 spaces             ^ 10 spaces
```

or this

```
printf ("|%-25s|%-15%|","hello", "world!!!");
```

outputs this:

```
|Hello                    |world!!!       |
//          ^ 20 spaces              ^ 7 spaces
```

If you omit `-`

```
printf ("|%25s|%15%|","hello", "world!!!");
```

you would get this:

```
|                    Hello|       world!!!|
//          ^ 20 spaces       ^ 7 spaces
```

I hope this helps, printing 90 spaces would be ridiculous.

@cigien beat me but go to c++ reference page.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 0):

### %-25s

Left-justify (-) a null-terminated string (s) parameter (%) with 25 (25) elements length/padding (hello)

### %-90s

Left-justify (-) a null-terminated string (s) parameter (%) with 90 (90) elements length/padding (world)

For more information you may see also:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/